# how to include current date and hour in kafka server.log filename?

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

we use kafka 1.1.0.

log4j.properties is like

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

Now logs are written like

- always write to `server.log`
- every hour, rename `server.log` to `server.log.2018-08-30-21`, create a new `server.log`
- repeat

is it possible to change the writing logic to

- now is `2018-08-30 21:59`, write log to `server.log.2018-03-30-21`
- when time passes to `2018-08-30 22:01`, write log to `server.log.2018-03-30-22`

by just changing some configuration files? I wonder if there is any timestamp variable I could use after `${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log.${something??}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format to **rollover at the beginning of every minute.**

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
```

Official log4j javadoc [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

Comment: Rolling files every minute is a little excessive, though. The question asked for hourly

Answer (score 0):

I think it always has to write to `server.properties`, or whatever string you hardcode there.

I doubt `log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File` property accepts a date pattern or other dynamic variable

The FileAppender docs don't indicate such, at least